# Error in resetting form field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope

I have a modal window where user is saving data , so below everytime when user open modal window i am reseting form fields to blank it is working as expected but angularjs form validation messages populating because of dirty check now i have added `$setPristine()` but it is throwing error `$setPristine()` is undefined.

main.html

```
<form id="editMessagesForm" name="editMessagesForm"
    novalidate class="border-box-sizing">
<div class="modalForm"> 
    <div class="modalBorder">
        <div class="row" ng-if="messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationKey">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldHeight">
                <label  class="col-md-4">Message Key:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="messageNotificationKey"
                        name="messageNotificationKey"
                        ng-model="messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationKey"
                        disabled="disabled">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldHeight">
                    <label  class="col-md-4">Message Type:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select name="mesgLookUpcode" class="form-control"
                            ng-model="messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationTypeCode" required
                            id="mesgLookUpcode"
                            ng-options="adminDataSource.id as adminDataSource.text for adminDataSource in adminDataSource">
                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                        </select>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldHeight">
                <label  class="col-md-4 required">Notification Name:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control"
                        ng-model="messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationName"
                        name="adminNotificationName"
                        required
                        id="adminNotificationName" txt-area-maxlen="128"
                        ng-disabled="readOnlyFlag"
                        data-tooltip-html-unsafe="<div>{{128 - messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationName.length}} characters left</div>"
                        tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'focus', false: 'never'}[messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationName.length >= 0 || messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationName.length == null ]}}"
                        tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-class = "bluefill"></textarea>
                        <p class="text-danger" ng-show="editMessagesForm.adminNotificationName.$touched && editMessagesForm.adminNotificationName.$error.required">Message Notification Name is required</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="modal-footer footerMargin">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right mousedwncall"
            ng-click="saveMessages()" ng-disabled="editMessagesForm.$invalid"
            ng-class="{disableSaveCls:editMessagesForm.$invalid}"
            >Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-left mousedwncall"
            ng-click="handleCancelMessageModal()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

main.js

```
 $scope.addMessageNotification = function() {
        clearNotificationForm();
        $scope.editMessagesForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.messageNotificationModal.open().center();
    };
    var clearNotificationForm = function () {
      $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationTypeCode = [];
      $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationName = '';
      $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationBody = '';
      $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationStartTime = '';
      $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationEndTime = '';
      $scope.messageNotificationDTO.activeFlag = '';
    };
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.messageNotificationDTO = {
    adminNotificationTypeCode: [],
    adminNotificationName:'',
    adminNotificationBody: '',
    adminNotificationStartTime: '',
    adminNotificationEndTime: '',
    activeFlag: ''
};
$scope.adminDataSource = adminData.data;

//Set notification grid config and dataSource
$scope.messageGridOptions = messageGridConfig.messagesGridOptions;
messageGridConfig.messagesGridOptions.dataSource = MessageAdminNotificationFactory.getNotificationDataSource();

//Save Notification
$scope.saveMessages = function() {
    MessageAdminNotificationFactory.saveMessageAdmin($scope.messageNotificationDTO).then(function() {
        $scope.messageNotificationModal.close();
        $scope.messageGridOptions.dataSource.read();
        clearNotificationForm();
    });

};
//Add new Notification
$scope.addMessageNotification = function() {
    $scope.messageNotificationModal.open().center();
};
var clearNotificationForm = function () {
  $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationTypeCode = [];
  $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationName = '';
  $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationBody = '';
  $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationStartTime = '';
  $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationEndTime = '';
  $scope.messageNotificationDTO.activeFlag = '';
  $scope.editMessagesForm.$setPristine();
};
```

error

```
 Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined
```

Comment: what is $setPristine() ??

Comment: Can you post your html as well? Your code looks correct.

Comment: I think your form name is wrong or something....post your HTML code....or provide a jsfiddle or plnkr

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ------------------------------------------Update------------------------------------------

dudeee I've put your entire form in the updated plunker why do you expect `$setPristine` to trigger ? when you are not triggering it.

you have made two mistakes first you need to bind `var clearNotificationForm = function ()` to the `$scope` like below, variable is NOT good enough to bind the function to your `$scope`

```
$scope.clearNotificationForm = function()
{
    // All your stuff to above $setPristine goes here
}
```

Second I don't see you triggering the above function any where in the form, you need to **trigger it** with the help of button like I did it in the updated plunker which you will find the link at the end of update.

```
<button class="button" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
```

In your case once you have tied the function to the `$scope` you button would look like this:

```
<button class="button" ng-click="clearNotificationForm ()">Reset</button>
```

In your case the function name will be as following but you need to first bind it to the `$scope`

```
$scope.clearNotificationForm = function()
{
}
```

If you find my post helpful please give me a like, I would highly appreciate it.

here is the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/feLPEU?p=preview)

---

## -------------------------------------First Response-----------------------------------

first make sure you name your input types with the same ng-model as following

```
<input name="name1" ng-model="messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationTypeCode" placeholder="Name" required/>
```

you need to define your parent object `messageNotificationDTO` with $scope and than inside it define the sub objects `adminNotificationTypeCode`

for example:

```
$scope.messageNotificationDTO = 
{ 
    "adminNotificationTypeCode": "",
    "adminNotificationName": ""
};
```

Set all the object to empty and then reset the form like:

```
$scope.reset = function()
{  
  $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationTypeCode = "";
  $scope.messageNotificationDTO.adminNotificationName  = "";

  $scope.form.$setPristine();
}
```

Here is a working example made from your controller code.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/feLPEU?p=preview)

Comment: I implemented your logic but its still throwing undefined setPristine , added my code in question

Comment: i am triggering `clearNotificationForm()` inside saveMessages method , we dont need to add additional button for reset i believe

Comment: Let me put your exact code on plunker to check if this problem is because of above mentioned updated code from ur main.js or ctrl.js

Comment: I just read through angularjs documentation and find out form name has to be object property like vm.formname , I implemented that and it worked but thanks for the help your answer also gave me some idea to understand angularjs validation.